# Match near similar characters/words

Tags: python, r

I have the following dataframe with columns X and Y,

```
    X                                   Y
1   SAN DIEGO                           FOND DU LAC
2   THE RIO GRANDE                      RIO GRANDE
3   RIO GRANDE                          RIO GRANDE
4   WEST TENNESSEE                      TENNESSEE
5   EP De SAN JOAQUIN                   De SAN JOAQUIN
6   SOUTHERN VIRGINIA                   VIRGINIA
7   SOUTHERN VIRGINIA                   SOUTHWESTERN VIRGINIA
8   EN COLOMBIA                         COLOMBIA
9   THE EP De NORTHERN CALIFORNIA       De NORTHERN CALIFORNIA
10  FLORIDA                             NEW JERSY
```

I want to get nonmatching rows, 1 and 10. Rows 2-9 are matches or close matches and are okay. My expected data frame is

```
    X                                   Y
1   SAN DIEGO                           FOND DU LAC
10  FLORIDA                             NEW JERSY
```

Answer (score 0):

In `R` we split the string by space in each column, check whether there is any `intersect` between the words, find the `lengths` of the `list` and subset the dataset where the length is 0

```
df1[!lengths(Map(intersect, strsplit(df1$X, "\\s+"), strsplit(df1$Y, "\\s+"))),]
#          X           Y
#1  SAN DIEGO FOND DU LAC
#10   FLORIDA   NEW JERSY
```

---

Instead of splitting by each column, we can also loop through the columns, do the `split`

```
df1[!lengths(do.call(Map, c(intersect, unname(lapply(df1, strsplit, split="\\s+"))))),]
#      X           Y
#1  SAN DIEGO FOND DU LAC
#10   FLORIDA   NEW JERSY
```

---

Or another option is `stringdist`

```
library(stringdist)
i1 <- with(df1, stringdist(X, Y, method = "qgram"))
df1[i1 %in% tail(sort(i1), 2),]
#          X           Y
#1  SAN DIEGO FOND DU LAC
#10   FLORIDA   NEW JERSY
```